# how to automate the network credential popup while adding domain user into local administrator group through powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

when we adding domain user into local administrator group from AD member graphically at that time we need to provide the network credentials.
i want to put this network credentials through powershell for that how i proceed ?

Comment: You will need to edit your question and add the code you are using before anyone will be able to help.

Comment: Besides missing code, your question as written, is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Computername = "PC01"
$Username = "Account1"
$GroupName = "Event Log Readers"
$DomainName = $env:USERDOMAIN
$Group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/$GroupName,group"   
$User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$Username,user"
$Group.Add($User.Path)
```

this is my code i want to add domain network credential into it how i add the credential code into it. username: ADadmin  and pass: linux@123